# Are Trangia and MSR fuel bottles inter changeable?

Tags: cooking, liquid-fuel-stoves

In other words, could I purchase a [1 litre Trangia fuel bottle](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Trangia-1-0L-Bottle-Safety-Valve/dp/B000Q6BQKG/ref=sr_1_3?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1337010774&sr=1-3) and the [MSR Dragonfly](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Msr-MSR-Dragonfly-Stove/dp/B002HRXJVQ/ref=pd_sim_sbs_sg_2) liquid-fuel camp stove and use them together? Or would the smaller, slightly more expensive [MSR fuel bottle](http://www.amazon.co.uk/MSR-Fuel-Bottles-650ml-22/dp/B00407HR4Q/ref=sr_1_1?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1337070218&sr=1-1) be the only option with the stove?

Comment: Great question, I'd be interested in the answer to this also.

Comment: Further to Hj's comment about corrosion I can confirm that this is a problem when methelated spirits is stored in an MSR bottle for use with a Trangia. Having carried meths in SIGG bottles before and found that quite quickly the threads to the screw caps start to seize up, and over time the meths corrodes holes in the sides - and no, I didn't get the two bottles replaced under guarantee although I tried - I bought an MSR bottle because it was described as a fuel bottle. Now I find that the same problem is developing with the thread corroding, but with a new twist; the meths itself seems to be

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with the bottles isn't so much the "bottle" as it is the pump. On an MSR bottle, a pump screws into the top, then a specific MSR-style hose (from a stove) attaches to the pump. On a Trangia, the attachment system is different (as per [This Gas Burner](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Trangia-742527-Gas-Burner/dp/B000N8JRB2/ref=pd_sim_sg_14), or [This One](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000S0FIIQ), depending on fuel, I think). The question in your case would be whether the threading is identical in the top of a [Trangia valve](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000W3CDF0) as it is on an [MSR fuel pump](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BBF2SS).

Based on [this forum topic discussion](http://www.spiritburner.com/fusion/showtopic.php?tid/21705/tp/1/) on fuel caps (they were not discussing pumps, but the fitment should be similar or the same), I'd say that they are the same (and might be the same as Sigg and Primus as well). I don't own a Trangia bottle so I can't confirm this, but that's what the web discussion seems to indicate. Also, pages such [This one](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/luontola/ultimate/kaplorer_eng.htm), and [This one](http://www.bushcraftuk.com/forum/showthread.php?t=17382) indicate that there is a great deal of adaptability with such attachments.

I do have a couple of unanswered concerns, such as what pressure the Trangia bottle can withstand, and how adaquate the pump seal would be. Otherwise, I think it's worth a shot. Perhaps someone who owns both items can demo it and let us know.

As an amusing side note, even without any answers this question pops up on the first page of a Google search for "MSR stove Trangia bottle".

Comment: You'd be surprised how quickly .SE questions pop to the top of Google, especially the tough ones (since there's no good answer elsewhere).

Comment: this guys blog suggests the same thing. That the threading is the same between most bottles (except Coleman and Soto). http://adventuresinstoving.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/how-much-white-gas-do-i-need.html. With that said, I probably will go with the same bottles are the stoves. Thanks guys

Answer (score 8):

I believe the threads are generally compatible, BUT that's not the issue. Trangia bottles are not metal (they're a plastic like material, perhaps floridated HDPE). Trangia bottles are NOT built to handle pressure and could be very dangerous if used with a pressurized white gas stove (such as a Whisperlite, Nova, Omnifuel, Dragonfly, etc).

On the other hand MSR bottles are aluminum. Aluminum can be corroded by alcohol. I've read reports of aluminum bottles being "eaten" by alcohol.

In short, I would not interchange the two brands.

HJ

[Adventures In Stoving](http://AdventuresInStoving.blogspot.com)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info on the Trangia bottles. I didn't know they weren't metal, and you answered the pressure question posed above. Interesting that you mention alcohol corroding MSR bottles, because I've known many people who carry alcohol in MSR bottles, and have done so for years. Perhaps those bottles are no longer safe for pressurized use? I wonder if someone has tested that.

Answer (score 2):

Although the threads may be similar (and even look the same) I've found that often the gaskets are not the same between bottles: flat gaskets, round, beveled and there is a corresponding difference in the rims of bottles: flat, round, beveled. Threads also tend to start in different places, and can have more or less bite/edge to them that can shred or deform the plastic threads on the pumps.

Having suffered enough leaks (and fires) by mix-mashing bottles and pumps (often without being able to identify why - gaskets were good etc.), I've adopted a policy of only using original bottles with pumps. This also is fairly standard among the professional outdoor guiding companies I'm familiar with.

Good practice: Use the original bottle to attach to the stove, and carry your extra fuel in another bottle with its own original cap, and refill the stove bottle as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I first bought a MSR Fuel Bottle (325 ml, aluminum) for packing denatured alcohol for my Trangia stove. Hiked with it for over a year with no leaks (safety-lock cap) or issues. Just bought a Trangia Fuel Bottle (300 ml, polythene) with push-button cap for dispensing fuel. Both high quality bottles. Discovered that the caps for each bottle thread into the other product bottle, no problem. Though the O-rings and cap lip are slightly different sizes, the Trangia dispensing cap easily threads and seals into the MSR bottle. The MSR safety-lock cap does thread into the Trangia bottle, however, the safety-lock cap does not completely seal on the Trangia bottle due to the (larger) metal reinforcing ring on the Trangia bottle preventing the cap from fully seating. I also tried the MSR Expedition Fuel Bottle Cap (non-safety cap) and that sealed on the Trangia bottle, but the cap lip and O-ring size were slightly larger than those of the original Trangia dispensing cap. I have not field tested the Trangia dispensing cap on the MSR bottle, but in a 15-minute inverted position leak-test there were no signs of fuel leakage from the thread/cap area. The Warning on the Trangia bottle warns "Don't pressurize the bottle." The MSR bottle advises "Contents under pressure."